# Цель: изменять значение filter:blur() изображения на сайте путем изменения положения ползунка <input type="range">

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хотел бы создать изображение и ползунок рядом с ним который будет отвечать за размытие изображения.

С первой частью задания справился на отлично, однако какой код надо написать в функции blurPic() я не знаю.

```
<img src="img_avatar.png" id="blurimg" alt="avatar"">
Blur:<input type="range" min="0" max="10" name="blurrange-box" value="5" id="blur" oninput="blurPic()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="img_avatar.png" id="blurimg" alt="avatar">
Blur:<input type="range" min="0" max="10" name="blurrange-box" value="5" 
id="blur" oninput="blurPic(this.value);">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function blurPic(value) {
         let img = document.getElementById('blurimg');
        img.style.filter = 'blur('+ value + 'px)';
    }
    //ИЛИ
    function blurPic() {
        let value = document.getElementById('blur').value;
        let img = document.getElementById('blurimg');
        img.style.filter = 'blur('+ value + 'px)';
    }
</script>
```